# How to calculate the difference in months between now and beginning of a loan in Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I am actually using Google Sheets (Google Drive), but I guess it's always easy to look for a translation of the formula from Excel.

So, say I have a mortgage or a loan issued at a specific date in the past, and I want to calculate the number of payments made...

I see I can insert in cells commands of the type:

`=TIME(YEAR(2001),MONTH(5),DAY(1))`

and also

`=TIME(YEAR(NOW()),MONTH(NOW()),DAY(NOW()))`

My interest is in subtracting the latter from the former, and outputting the number of months elapsed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Excel, if you have a cell, say A1 that has a date in it. You can determine the number of months that have passed with:

```
=(Year(today())-year(A1))*12+month(today())-Month(A1)
```

Answer (score 2):

*Suppose the Loan Date 27-03-2015 is in Cell A2 and Current Date 27/01/2018 is in B2. 
So to get the months Elapsed DATEDIF  function can be used also.*

```
=DATEDIF(A2,B2,"m")
```

or

```
=DATEDIF(D386,TODAY(),"m")
```

*Hope this help you.*

Comment: Thank you. I don't have enough reputation to upvote...

Comment: No problem,,, Vote as Answer if you are allowed to do so,,,, and keep asking :-) .